# Python function returns different return values in console vs. in script

Tags: python, import, pycharm, integer-overflow

I am trying to clean up my code. I put a very simple integer operation into a function. If I execute the function definition and call in the console, it works fine. If I import the function def and run in in script, it fails (looks like an integer over-/underflow, but I would not understand why)

Here is what works. I execute the following in console

```
def calculate_absolute_week_span(first_week, first_year, last_week, last_year):
  start = 52 * (first_year - 1900) + first_week
  end = 52 * (last_year - 1900) + last_week
  return start, end

training_start, training_end = calculate_absolute_week_span(1, 2010, 34, 2018)
```

Output: training_start: 5721

Now I run the same code as script (PyCharm).

```
from preprocessing import calculate_absolute_week_span
training_start, training_end = calculate_absolute_week_span(1, 2010, 34, 2018)
```

Output this time: training_start: -62556

Similarly, training_end works fine in the first example and returns 6170, wheres I see -61426 in the lower case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't use Pycharm, I just put the second block of code in another script file and ran it with `python scriptname.py`

Comment: Are you sure it's importing from the file you think? If you add a print line to the function, do you see that output?

Comment: I tried. No, I don't see anything printed! The function seems to be executing, but there is nothing printed. Weird... I am 99.99% sure there cannot possibly any other module "preprocessing" nor a function "calculate_absolute_week_span" anywhere else on this machine

Comment: So, then, what is PyCharm actually doing? It is not executing the function properly (obviously), but returning some return value. The (incorrect) return values can be reproduced.. it's not just random anywhere in memory

Comment: What happens if you completely delete the function definition?

Comment: Maybe something in the importing? from preprocessing import calculate_absolute_week_span
I just created a Pycharm project, but just copied the function (without the import) and the result is correct.

Comment: With import it worked  as well - the function saved in a file "preprocessing.py" in the same folder.  http://twenkid.com/stack/p
Can you debug it step by step and watch the values or add prints inside the function etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by rebooting the machine...